# When and why to use Django development server?

Tags: python, django

I understand that it's simple and doesn't require any installation whatsoever, but are there any other reasons to use it for long-term development instead of Apache with mod_wsgi? As a Django newbie, I just find deployment from development to live (Apache) environment quite cumbersome and annoying, so the question that comes into my mind is: Isn't it simpler to just use mod_wsgi on localhost too? Only mention about this in [Django manual](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/) I found was:

> We've included this with Django so you
>   can develop things rapidly, without
>   having to deal with configuring a
>   production server -- such as Apache --
>   until you're ready for production.

Comment: I don't think so. As that snippet suggests, it's just easier than setting up apache and mod_wsgi before you can even begin playing around.

Comment: @rebus - You can setup Apache/mod_wsgi to monitor for code changes as well. See http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ReloadingSourceCode#Monitoring_For_Code_Changes

Comment: Yes, yes, I know, i should have mention it too, I make it sound like impossible with that comment. But when developing on multiple computers I find it easier just to run dev server then configuring apache with mod_wsgi. It is also suggested to use automatic reloading behaviour with mod_wsgi only for development.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You sometimes *need* the production setup locally when you're developing. I've needed it when I was messing with some subdomain related code that tied into the application and needed to mimic my real server locally.

However, for most things, the dev server is a big win. Here are a few points.

1. Like rebus mentioned, the auto restart.
2. Tracebacks on the console and useful debugging information.
3. You can stick `pdb.set_trace()` into parts of your code and get a debugger prompt while a view method is executing if you want to look at stuff.
4. The entire stack runs as a single user (you) which you have complete control over.
5. One command to start and run.

These come with a price which is reduced performance and inability to handle real life traffic. That's why you need a *real* web server to run it in production.

Comment: +1, You can also embed [ipython shell](http://ipython.scipy.org/doc/manual/html/interactive/reference.html#embedding-ipython).

Comment: you can also run debug/traced runserver from your favorite IDE (eclipse, pycharm, etc..)

Answer (score 2):

When I create a simple Django app for local users to populate data into a DB i usually leave it running with the development server. I've never had any problems... If it's in a local server and not exposed to the internet it should be ok to use it.